# Не получается вывести через db2cmd подробную информацию о приложениях, подключенных к DB2

Tags: db2, ibm

Подскажите пожалуйста. Впервые столкнулся с такой проблемой(ver.DB2 10.5 type lic. CPU Option - Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1)

Команды выполняю через консоль db2cmd от имени администратора. При выводе подробной информации о приложениях подключенных к DB2 использую следующую команду:

> ****db2 list applications for db SAMPLE show detail****

выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

> **SQL1428N Программа уже подключена к узлу "DB2" , а поданная команда требует для успешного исполнения подключения к узлу "TCP01"**

Если кто-то сталкивался, поделитесь своим опытом пожалуйста!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: I need to look to view detailed information about the applications connected to my database. Returns an error when executing a command in db2cmd